# SwiftUI Building Lists and Navigation - Cannot render canvas while following tutorial - Updating took more than 5 seconds / crashed

Tags: swift, xcode, swiftui

Following the SwiftUI tutorial and ran into this problem. Strangely it worked the first few times then suddenly decided it didn't want to work anymore. Been googling all over, to find out why I suddenly can't preview the row I have created while following and slightly adapting the SwiftUI tutorials. The errors I get above the canvas say "Updating took more than 5 seconds" or "Cannot preview in this file -  crashed".

Diagnostics file says:

```
Check ~/Library/Logs/DiagnosticReports for crash logs from your application.

==================================

|  RemoteHumanReadableError: Failed to update preview.
|  
|  The preview process appears to have crashed.
|  
|  Error encountered when sending 'previewInstances' message to agent.
|  
|  ==================================
|  
|  |  RemoteHumanReadableError: The operation couldn’t be completed. (BSServiceConnectionErrorDomain error 3.)
|  |  
|  |  BSServiceConnectionErrorDomain (3):
|  |  ==BSErrorCodeDescription: OperationFailed
```

I've googled that and saw some people saying to add ".environmentObject(UserData()))" to the preview but then I get cannot find user data errors.

others said problems with the emulator

others mentioned the swiftDelegate file but as I've built it as a SwiftUI app that doesn't exist and is replaced with an app file. Annoying tried rebuilding it with the other life cycle but that produces the same errors.

I am completely lost.

The contents of the file I am trying to see is:

```
  import SwiftUI

struct houseRow: View {
    var house: House
    var body: some View {
            VStack {
                HStack {
                    house.image
                    .resizable()
                    .frame(width: 50, height: 50)
                    Text(house.address + ",")
                    Text(house.town + ",")
                    Text(house.postcode)
                }
            }
    }
}

struct houseRow_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
    houseRow(house: houses[1])
    }
}
```

so it is pretty basic, it stopped working when I had 2 previews and tried grouping them, now it won't work at all. Tried the usual restart everything... nada. Is it a problem with Xcode?

Any ideas will be welcomed with open arms! Thanks!

Comment: Needed complete reproducible example to debug

Comment: You mean the whole project? What is the easiest way to provide that?

Comment: @LiamRothwell you can upload on GitHub and share a link here

Comment: and in preview, you have pass houses[1]. Where you declare houses array?

Comment: Your preview code some thing like this : ```struct houseRow_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        houseRow(house: House(image: "image", address: "address", town: "town", postcode: "code"))
    }
}
```

Comment: Try adding a House() directly into the preview instead of referencing houses[1] and see if it works.